# Posting data with GCM push notification

Tags: curl, google-cloud-messaging, push, service-worker

I'm trying out the GCM push notification API. So far it works fine, but I'm  not sure how to post additional data.

I followed the steps on this page: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/step-07

So I ended up writing a `curl` request like this:

`curl --header "Authorization: key=myKey" --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[myRegistrationId], \"additionalData\": {\"user_id\":\"1\"}}"`

And then my `sw.js` (my service worker)

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    console.log('Push message', event);
    var title = 'test a';
    event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification(title, {
            body: 'The Message',
            icon: '/assets/img/logo.png',
            tag: 'my-tag'
        }));
});
```

Is there a way to read out the `additionalData` in this event? Or am I not supposed to do it like this?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: You may post additional data in push Notification but there is data size limitation.

Comment: But how do I actually post it and read it in my push event?

Comment: server side which language you are using

Comment: I mean, with the `curl` request I posted in my question. I tried to add `additionalData`.

Comment: Refer Android hive gcm example you will get the proper solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using one of the libraries in https://github.com/web-push-libs, they hide the complexity associated with push payloads and they support both the standard web push protocol (currently supported by Firefox and soon used by default in Chrome) and the proprietary GCM protocol (which will be deprecated in Chrome sooner or later).

Currently there are libraries for Node.js, PHP, Python and Java.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [step](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/step-07) and did not change anything.

I tried `POST` with **cURL**:

```
curl --request POST --url localhost:8080/api/send-push-msg --header 'content-type: application/json' --data '{"subscription":{"endpoint":"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/fKr7EsvRiyA:APA.....[Changes with your data]","keys":{"p256dh":"Your Key","auth":"Your Auth"}},"data":"Your Messages Here","applicationKeys":{"public":"Your Public Key Server","private":"Private Key Server"}}'
```

It worked well for me. :)