# Why is the payload lost from FCM push notification?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have integrate FCM using a NodeJS app server and am able to successfully send Push Notifications using below code. I am using Service Worker on client side to handle the Push notifications in a PWA

```
fetch(firebase_url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `key=${firebase_auth}`
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        "to" : recieverToken,
        "data" : {
            "text": "Hello world"
        },
        "notification": {
            "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
            "body": "5 to 1"
        }
    })
})
```

The problem I have is that the `payload` data is `null` as shown and I couldn't find the reason behind it

[image]

Comment: It seems you're not sending it right. Because nothing that you sent is there. Not just `data`, but `notification` and `to` as well. Any chance you missed something in the docs?

Comment: Exactly. I don't think the to field will be part of the event. It's just used to uniquely identify the user the message was supposed to be sent to

Comment: instead of `body`, did you try passing `data`?

Comment: That's a normal POST using fetch. You cannot replace POST body with data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Posting data with GCM push notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966954/posting-data-with-gcm-push-notification)

Comment: You need to use the Web Push standard to send notifications with payload.

Comment: Are you receiving any error responses?

Answer (score -1):

```
function post(postkey,messageTitle,messageBody) {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
        headers : {
            Authorization : 'key=%%YOUR FCMKEY%%'
        },
        contentType : 'application/json',
        data : JSON.stringify({
            "to": postkey,
            "notification": {
                "icon": 'qc/logo_Tran.png',
                "click_action": '%%YOUR URL%%',
                "body": messageBody,
                "title": messageTitle
            }
        }) ,
        success : function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error : function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr.error);                   
        }
    });              
}
```

Comment: This does **not** answer the question in a useful way. _why_ do you believe this is the answer? _how_ does it work? Simply telling someone to _change their code_ without any context or meaning does not help them learn what they did wrong, and is also not useful for future readers.